# Is it possible to get a changeset diagram for a parent and child branches in TFS?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Suppose that you have two branches, a parent and a child one, in TFS (not DevOps).

Is it possible to obtain an automatic diagram of their respective progress, with the changesets (or even better, Work Items) developed in each one after the branching event, and any merge occurred between them?

i.e. (CS stands for changeset):

```
Parent branch (CS 123) ------------------- Child branch (from CS 123)
      |                                             |
    CS 124                                          |
      |                                             |
    CS 125                                          |
      |                                             |
    CS 126                                        CS 127
      |                                             |
    CS 128          ------merge----->             CS 128
      |                                             |
    CS 129                                          |
```

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be achieved in tfs. You can use Visual studio as below Shamrai answered

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think so. You can use Visual Studio to:

1. View the hierarchy of your branches: [View the branch hierarchy of a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-branch-hierarchy-team-project?view=azure-devops)
2. Track change-set from the [history view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged?view=azure-devops#to-view-the-tracking-changeset-window-from-the-history-window-of-a-branch-or-file).
3. If you have linked work items, you can view their [merge path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged?view=azure-devops#to-view-the-tracking-changeset-window-from-a-work-item-that-is-linked-to-a-changeset).

Additionally, you can try [Branch Visualization](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.BranchVisualization).